# How to choose where a file is saved using FFMPEG

Tags: python, windows, ffmpeg

I was wondering how I could go about doing telling FFMPEG where to save files it converts, it keeps making the files save way too deep in my computer.

```
check_output("ffmpeg -i " + location + " -vn -ar 44100 -ac 1 -b:a 32k -f wav audio.wav", shell=True)
```

I use that in my program to convert the files to wav.

Comment: maybe use `cwd` when running your command? or absolute path for the output

Answer (score 2):

The question is totally unrelated to python.

I suggest stopping using `shell=True`, because that invokes a shell to call your subprocess, adding useless overhead (invoke a process to invoke another process). Another advantage is that it allows you to provide the command line as a list of parameters, which frees you from quote/space hell and is simpler.

That said, just add the folder to the destination filename and it will be generated there:

```
filename = 'audio.wav'
destination = r'C:\Some\Folder'
subprocess.check_output(["ffmpeg", 
    "-i", location,
    "-vn",
    "-ar", "44100",
    "-ac", "1",
    "-b:a", "32k",
    "-f", "wav",
    os.path.join(destination, filename)
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a huge help!